# String Alphabetizer - Not Alphabetizing first word

Tags: c#, alphabetical-sort

Newbie here stuck on a small issue. 
I am just doing a small easy task to work on skills but I cant out this little issue. 
Essentially I am parsing a sentence string through a method that will take each word apart and alphabetize each word. However I can't work out why the first word never alphabetizes. Any help is much appreciated.

```
static string Alphabetize(string word)
    {
        char[] a = word.ToCharArray();

        Array.Sort(a);

        return new string(a);
    }

    static void Scrambler(string sentence)
    {
        string tempStore = "";
        List<string> sentenceStore = new List<string>();
        Regex space = new Regex(@"^\s+$");


        // Store each word in a list
        for (int c = 0; c < sentence.Length; c++)
        {
            if (!space.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(sentence[c])))
            {
                tempStore += Convert.ToString(sentence[c]);
                if (sentence.Length - 1 == c)
                {
                    sentenceStore.Add(tempStore);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sentenceStore.Add(tempStore);
                tempStore = "";
            }
        }


        foreach (string s in sentenceStore)
        {

            Console.Write(Alphabetize(s));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Scrambler("Hello my name is John Smith");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program in single step mode to see what happens with each word? Also, consider using `String.Split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does "alphabetize" (sort) your first word.
When "alphabetizeing" with `Array.Sort()`, it takes Uppercase Letters first in alphabetic order then Lowercase Letters in alphabetic order.

so `"cCbBaA"` for example should become `"ABCabc"`

or `"Smith"` for example should become `"Shimt"`

and `"Hello"` will remain `"Hello"`

on a side note: you should consider using `String.Split()`

Comment: Oh!!! Great point, thanks for that. I implemented the String.Split Method, worked perfectly. Thank-you!

Comment: @kristian You are welcome! Feel free to mark my Answer as "Correct Answer" if it solved your problem. (: